# Why is z-index not independent of stacking context?

Tags: css, z-index

An element that has a high z-index may below another element that has a low z-index, only because the ancestors' z-index of the lower one provides a higher stacking context for this element.

Because of this, it's impossible to overlay an element from a lower stacking context without a major change in the CSS or HTML code. On the other hand, using the z-index property would be simples if it would be an "absolute" value (higher z-index -> higher position on the z axis).

My question is, why was this implemented this way in the browsers and the standards?

Comment: By absolute value I am assuming you mean relative to the `body` element?

Comment: Yes, this is more exact.

Comment: 6 of one, a half dozen of the other.  If it were absolute, you wouldn't be able to have sets of things that overlapped properly, e.g. 10 things with a class of `.foo`.  Every child would have to have a different z-index.  Granted, the logic behind your question has driven many people crazy at some point, but if it were different it would do the same.

Comment: What is a "higher stacking context" and a "lower stacking context"?

Comment: The web-page may consist of different modules. The modularity would be ruined if all modules used the same `z-index` scale. Adding a module to the page would be non-trivial, since you'd have to adjust all `z-index` values of that module. That'd be a mess. Why would you want that?

Comment: My problem was I wanted to add a shadow under a div element (not a simple shadow, so box-shadow wasn't enough). The shadow was an img with position:absolute, and the div had position:relative. I would have positioned the shadow relative to the div, if I would have put the img inside the div. But in this case, the div couldn't overlay the shadow.

But you're right, sometimes (or usually) the "absolute z-index" would be a bad thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think **cwolves** has the proper answer, and the way it is now it's probably the most logic.
To help understanding you can think of **z-index** like Photoshop layers.
If you have a folder of layers above another folder, the wrapped layers can't obviously be arranged outside their parents, unless you move them from a folder to another.

Or think of boxes: you can arrange things inside a box, but you can't arrange things from two different boxes, unless you move them from a box to another.

If you're running into the case where you need a different arrangement, you probably need to re-think your markup to allow this.

Comment: The box analogy makes sense because *CSS visuals happen to be [all about boxes*](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html).

Comment: I think you are right, if the stacking context makes impossible to overlay an element, the mistake is probably in the HTML structure.